# wordpress htaccess valid url for uppercase and lowercase URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

hi guys question how to validate an Uppercase when my folder setup for wordpress is like this

http://www.myhomepage.com/us/en/

but I want it to be like this for the url

http://www.myhomepage.com/US/en/

is there any way to manipulate it on htaccess or wordpress setting?

TIA

Comment: What is your htaccess code now?

Comment: the basic code 
`code
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding the `NC` flag as below.

```
# BEGIN WordPress <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,NC] 
</IfModule> # END WordPress
```